# Finite runs on a transition system

Tags: isabelle

I want to write a predicate that would state that a transition system cannot have infinite runs from a state s. So consider the transition system is given by R, then the definition I have come up with is:

```
inductive finite_runs for R where         
"(∀ s'. R s s' ⟶ finite_runs R s') ⟹ finite_runs R s"
```

Is this the simplest way I can state this fact in Isabelle? In particular, I have browsed the Archive of Formal Proofs (the rewriting and labeled transition theories) but got no simpler solution.

Comment: I think your first case is actually unnecessary since it is a special case of the second one. If there are no transitions from some state `s`, then the universal quantifier in the second case is trivially satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `Wellfounded.termip` in the standard library. I think it should do exactly what you want.

It is basically an abbreviation using `Wellfounded.accp`, which does the same thing but going ‘backwards’.

Comment: the r^-^- in where "termip r ≡ accp (r¯¯)" stands for the backward version of r^+^+ I guess?

Comment: Without checking: No, I think it's simply the converse of the relation (i.e. `{(y,x) | (x,y) ∈ R}`).

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that finite runs means absence of infinite runs, then you can use the strong-normalization-on predicate `SN_on` of the AFP-entry Abstract-Rewriting. However your definition permits also runs like

a -> a -> a -> ...

which is not permitted by `SN_on`.